# Access server with client certificate using s_client but not curl?

Tags: curl, ssl, nginx, openssl

I am using nginx for my web server with client certificate authentication. The relevant part of the config is:

```
ssl_certificate        /usr/local/etc/nginx/certs/ssl.crt;
ssl_certificate_key    /usr/local/etc/nginx/certs/ssl.key;
ssl_client_certificate /usr/local/etc/nginx/certs/server_chain.crt;
ssl_verify_client on;
ssl_verify_depth 2;
```

The client certificates are signed by another server that has a certificate from a root CA. I.e, I want to accept clients that have a certificate chain as follows:

```
CA -> intermediate CA -> client
```

Therefore the file server_chain.crt is made by:

```
cat intermediate_ca.crt root_ca.crt > server_chain.crt
```

Now, I can sucessfully access the server by issuing the command:

```
openssl s_client -connect localhost:443 -tls1 -cert client.crt \
    -key client.key -CApath root_ca.crt -state -debug`
```

and then typing `GET /api`

But if I try to reach the same service by using:

```
curl -v -s -k --key client.key --cert client.crt https://localhost/api
```

I get:

```
<html>
<head><title>400 No required SSL certificate was sent</title></head> 
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>400 Bad Request</h1></center>
<center>No required SSL certificate was sent</center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.6.0</center>
</body>
</html>
```

I also can not access the `localhost/api` page from a web browser with a client certificate installed. Something that works if I turn off client verification.

Any ideas on what's wrong?

Comment: You're calling the files `client.*` with OpenSSL and `cert.*` with cURL. Is it just a typo in this question, or are you actually not using the same files? I also suspect cURL might not send any client cert to a server certificate it doesn't trust. I might be worth using your CA cert with cURL too instead of `-k`.

Comment: The naming is just a typo, sorry. But I will definetely try the other stuff. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, so the error was totally unrelated to nginx. Turns out curl has no engine for running ssl by default on OS X. Therefore, curl never sent any certificate to the server.

Comment: I too encountered this with curl 7.47.0 on Ubuntu 16.04. However, CentOS 7 works fine  with curl 7.29.0

Answer (score 2):

Could you try specifying the path. Old version of curl seems to have some bug:

```
curl -v -s -k --key ./client.key --cert ./client.crt https://localhost/api
```

https://help.mulesoft.com/s/article/Received-No-required-SSL-certificate-was-sent-Error-Sending-a-Request-Via-Client-Certificate-Enabled-DLB-Due-to-Curl-Version

Comment: Yes, this "bug" got me.  `curl 7.29.0`

`* warning: certificate file name "client.crt" handled as nickname; please use "./client.crt" to force file name`
`* NSS: client certificate not found: client.crt`

Answer (score 1):

This might have changed since then, but as of today, the installed curl *can* use client side certificates. But because it's linking to Mac OS's SSL libraries there's a couple of gotchas:

1. The certificate needs to be in PKCS12 format. You can convert what you have with the following:

```
     cat client.key client.crt intermediate_ca.crt > bundle.pem
     openssl pkcs12 -export -in bundle.pem -out bundle.p12
```

2. Run curl with the `--cert bundle.p12:*password*` option
3. The showstopper gotcha. Either curl or the underlying libraries do ***NOT*** correctly send intermediate certificates: only the client-side certificate is sent. You can verify this with a packet capture on packets going towards the server: the issuer and subject names are visible in cleartext.

Comment: You also need to add `--cert-type P12` in the `curl` command, otherwise you'll have an error saying "could not load PEM client certificate".